# i don't understand why string comparison is returning false even when the strings are equal

Tags: java, android, string-comparison

```
s = ans.getText().toString();

jum.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3){
        String selected = jum.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();
        if(s.equals(selected))
        {
            //jum.setItemChecked(arg2, true);
            ans.setText("correct");
        }
        else
        {
            ans.setText("incorrect");
        }

    }
});
```

Here `ans` is an EditText ans `jum` is a listview. I am trying to compare the string entered by user in edittext with the string of the item in listview that he clicks on.

Comment: *"i don't understand why string comparison is returning false even when the strings are equal"* It *isn't*. So the question you need to ask yourself is: How are the strings different, in a way I can't immediately see? [`select` isn't broken](http://pragmatictips.com/26)

Comment: Try logging both `s` and `selected` to really see what values they contain.

Comment: Also remember that strings might sometime contains characters you won't see. It might not be the case for you, but often I find myself comparing "test" to "test\n" or something similar. Watch out for those cases!

Comment: as an example, i would like to quote that the listview has 3 items cat, dog, lion. in the edittext i entered cat and then clicked the first item (i.e. cat) in the list. Now the expected answer shall have been correct but it's printing incorrect instead

Comment: put this `Log.e(s, selected);` inside `onItemClick(...)` and check what value you are getting.

Answer (score -1):

```
jum.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            String selected = jum.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();
            s= ans.getText().toString();

            if(s.equals(selected))
            {
                //jum.setItemChecked(arg2, true);
                ans.setText("correct");
            }
            else
            {
                ans.setText("incorrect");
            }

        }
    });
```